# How to stream logs from azure mobile services into console

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I just found a nice way of streaming logs from azure websites http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics-logging-and-instrumentation/#streamlogs but cannot find a way to do the same from azure mobile services.

Is it possible?

Larsi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no tool that does that automatically, but you can use the Azure Command-Line Interface (CLI) to get the logs in real-time from Azure Mobile Services. You can have it running on a loop constantly calling `azure mobile log` to get the latest logs and dump them into the console.

The post at http://www.thejoyofcode.com/A_Mobile_Services_Log_Watcher_Day_6_.aspx shows one way of implementing that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at this codeplex Project . It 's a wpf application that allow You to download and query the log of your azure mobile service.

http://amslogviewer.codeplex.com/

and http://jeremiedevillard.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/azure-mobile-log-viewer-an-app-to-easily-query-azure-mobile-log-data/